# Crystal Reports (VS 2008) not printing Barcode Font on Server

Tags: asp.net, crystal-reports

I have a web application that has a report. I export this report as PDF and send it to the client. On this report I have a field that has a font set to a non-standard windows font (i.e. a barcode font). The barcode font is a TTF font.

On my dev machine, I installed the font, printed the report, barcode was displayed.

On the server, I have installed the font, but when printing it, it seems to have reverted back to the Arial font.

This is using the version of Crystal supplied with VS2008.

Any ideas?

I have un-installed and re-installed the font...

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've been in a similar situation before myself:

Try opening the Fonts folder from Control Panel and open the font you installed to see the default sample text.  If it looks good, try the report again as it may magically work.  I've had to do this before when using an older TrueType barcode font on newer versions of Windows.

If that doesn't work, try verifying the report again, and save it as a new file instead of overwriting the existing one.

Comment: Tried your suggestions, but with no effect. Turns out what does do the trick though is a reboot of the server. Thanks for answering though, answer awarded :)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. I have copied the fonts into server but no result. 
But after copying the fonts into the client computer the problem was rectified.